# server-client where the client listens and responds in a loop doesn't work (python)

Tags: python, sockets, pycharm, python-sockets

I'm building a Client-Server connection for an assignment. The server basically runs everything and the client only receives messages from the server and responds when the server needs it to.
For some reason, I can't build a client that repeatedly listens and then responds.
I thought that I could just listen with `socket.recv()` and it ended up just stopping everything.
this is what I ended up with after some tweaking (for the **client**) :

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 65432
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.connect((HOST, PORT))
conn.setblocking(False)
while True :
    try :
        msg_lgn = len(conn.recv(1024,socket.MSG_PEEK))
        server_message = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        print('Server Sent:\n' + server_message)
        if server_message == 'exit':
            break
    except :
        conn.send(input().encode())
conn.close()
```

I set it to non-blocking so it won't hang on the `conn.recv()` and move on to input in the exception, but then it just freezes on the input.
does the server close the connection every time recv() gets nothing ? why is this happening ?
I just want the client to receive messages whenever the server sends them, and when the server doesn't send, the client will send the server it's input.

would appreciate any help!
Lidor

Edit : the server file is much bigger, so i'll show the important parts.

```
#imported some classes for the game itself also (that i've created), but has nothing to do with the problem
import socket
import time
import threading

def startGame(conn):
#this is where the servers sends the questions and receives answer (pretty basic send and recv)

# Establish Client-Server Connection
HOST = 'localhost'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(3)
# Use Threading to start the game for an new player
while True:
    if playerCount < 3:
        (conn, addr) = s.accept()
        playerCount += 1
        x = threading.Thread(target=startGame, args=(conn,))
        x.start()
# Close Server Socket
s.close()
```

Comment: TCP streams are not message oriented, you can't just assume a single 1024-byte read corresponds to a single write on the other side of the pipe. You should figure out a length + payload (or a TLV style) encoding for your messaging instead.

Comment: I'll add the server to the first message

Comment: In general, you don't want to use nonblocking sockets; they're... not easy to work with. Also, you'll probably want to use `.sendall()` since you're not checking what `.send()` returns.

Comment: what wrong with non-blocking sockets ? that's the only thing that allowed me use the try and except. your'e saying the problem for me is the send?

Comment: can anyone help out ?